# Platform for Quantitative equity portfolio

Tags: portfolio-management, quantitative

What are the most popular platforms used for quantitative equity portfolio management/research?

I've only used Barra so far for their factor models. Is there any specific feature or model you think that'll be really helpful for such a product?

I am looking for a product so that I can focus on idea/strategy generation rather than spending a lot of time in preparing data or other fundamental work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few that have overlaps/synergies with Barra:

- Wharton Research Data Services (WRDS)
- S&P Capital IQ Compustat
- FactSet Research Systems
- Eze OMS Portfolio Modeling and Analytics
- Axioma Portfolio Analytics
- Fincluster fcbank

Comment: Thanks for the list. FactSet and Compustat seem to be value-adding as there is some intelligence helps with investment decisions.

Answer (score 1):

Your need to also specify the frequency at which you are trading.

For long to medium u can also consider ITG

For Day trading you can consider Flextrade, Portware

If u are solo then interactive brokers. If you are adventurous then quantstrat

Comment: ITG looks very promising as its system is backed up by quant research results. I am hoping the tool can provide some building blocks or some modules for quant research. Will appreciate if you know anything else relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Bloomberg functions PORT OPT and MARS provide internal factor models for many asset classes + ability to use your own models in optimization.